# After I have set up a Ubuntu Virtual Machine using VMware, how do I increase the alloted desk size partition?

Tags: vmware

After I have set up a Ubuntu Virtual Machine using VMware, how do I increase the alloted desk size partition?  I have everything on a 2TB external drive.  So I am not going to run out of space.  But during the process of loading all the required software to do Android APP development, I have run out of space.

I followed the steps from https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004047  whick are also described https://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Disk-Space-in-VMware

I increased the disk size on the VMware side and this was condluced with

[image]

The next step is to use the command line on Ubuntu.  But when I started Ubuntu, I saw this after power-up:

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Is this the root partition `/`? can you add to your question the result of `findmnt  --df` to see the layout of your disk.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a VM you define the size of the Virtual Drive.
No matter if the Hard drive has 2TB of disk space, if you defined a virtual drive of 20GB you'll only be able to use 20GB.
The best is probably to create a new VM with a bigger virtual hard drive, for example of 50GB, and adding additional virtual hard drives. Make it grow as the space is used, so at the beginning will use much less space (thin provisioning).

Take in count that in an external drive the IO performance will be bad. If you use too big virtual disks you'll probably experiment performance issues and eventually hang ups. I don't recommend to use VMs over external hard drives. It is too easy to get a disconnection and get corruption TBH.
If you have to, I recommend that at least you use USB 3.0 or USB-C and SATA3 compatible drives.